# Renaming a set of files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have 100 files named `sub1.txt, sub2.txt,..., sub100.txt`. I like to rename them as `all1.txt, all2.txt,..., all100.txt`. How can one do this in linux (unix)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any way that this could be migrated to [Linux/Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), rather than [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The script below will rename an arbitrary number of file with the pattern `sub*.txt`. This also does a dry-run thanks to the `echo`. Simply remove the `echo` once you are satisfied with the results.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in sub*.txt; do
  echo mv "$file" "all${file#sub}"
done
```

Comment: remove the echo, or `|sh` ;-)

Comment: @mvds when putting scripts on SO that are destructive in nature, I *always* include the `echo` to make the script benign until the user is satisfied with its results.

Comment: Good policy. Will remember that.

Answer (score 2):

Using the util-linux-ng version of `rename`:

```
rename sub all sub*.txt
```

Using the Perl script version of `rename`:

```
rename 's/^sub/all/' sub*.txt
```

Comment: +1 pretty much every file renaming question on this site has a simple answer: use `rename`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `seq 1 100`; do mv sub$i.txt all$i.txt; done
```

or

```
for i in sub*.txt; do j=`echo $i|sed -e s/sub/all/`; mv $i $j; done
```

Comment: Since the OP tagged this with bash, I would use the shell's native brace expansion of `for i in {1..100}` instead of calling the external binary `seq`.  Also, and this may just be my pedantry coming through, but use `$()` instead of backticks for command substitution because the latter is not POSIX and also isn't easily nestable.

Comment: True, but as a general approach using external programs like this will (hopefully) teach the OP to solve the next problem without coming back here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for F in sub*.txt ; do mv $F all${F#sub}; done
```

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variable names

Comment: @siegeX generally a good idea, but don't really need to in this case.

Comment: @kurumi why does it matter here?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -e 'Dir["sub*.txt"].each {|x| File.rename(x, x.gsub(/^sub/,"all") ) }'
```

Answer (score -1):

There is always a new way to do it:

```
$ ls sub*.txt | tr -d "sub" | xargs -I{} mv sub{} all{}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Parsing `ls` should be avoided if at all possible. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @SiegeX: Oh! I see. Didn't know that. What about `find`?

Comment: `tr` does not do substitution. letters s, u or b will be "deleted", not the word "sub"

Comment: @Pablo: Parsing `find` is a fine alternative and I commonly use it with its `-print0` flag in conjunction with the `read` builtin delimited on NUL.  Also, POSIX-2004 compliant versions of `find` can have their `-exec` terminated with a `+` to have it behave in exactly the same manner as if the args were piped to `xargs`

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz, like i said, it won't work because `tr` will remove characters, not a whole word. You don't want it remove s,u or b in other parts of the file name.

Comment: @kurumi: check out OP's question. His names are all like `sub1.txt`, `sub2txt`.